# VC++ reports crash at runtime when implementing callback using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am in need to implement a callback method using a unique_ptr of another class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
void Show(std::vector<int> a, int b) {std::cout << "Hello " << " " << b << std::endl;}
};

class B
{
public:
void SetCB(std::function<void(std::vector<int> ,int)> callb);
std::function<void(std::vector<int> ,int)> cb;
};

void B::SetCB(std::function<void(std::vector<int> ,int)> callb)
{
cb= callb;
}

int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<A> a1 = std::make_unique<A>();
std::unique_ptr<B> b1 = std::make_unique<B>();
b1->SetCB([&](std::vector<int> a, int b){a1->Show(a,b);});
std::vector<int> y;
b1->cb(y,4);
}
```

I am getting run time read access error violation in VC++ - how can we implement a callback using unique_ptr with some parameters using std::bind or other ways?

```
$ c++ -std=c++14 try68.cpp

                 ^
```

Is it not possible to set a callback methods using unique_ptr?

Comment: Is this a new curriculum question? I think we've seen this a few times already.

Comment: Yes - I am getting run time exception in VC++ - the compilation went fine with solution provided

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. It [compiles and runs](https://rextester.com/OGAYB34671) for me.

Comment: I found the issue - in my original code I was setting the callback before object was constructed, Rectified the same and it works fine now - thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word of advice, you should be very careful using a lambda callback that captures **local variables by reference**. If your callback is returned from the scope of the `a1` variable (which is the main() function, so your example is ok), then the expression `a1->Show(a,b)` will trigger undefined behavior since `a1` is a *dangling reference*. If you your callback function stays in the scope of the captured variables then your code is ok, but if you need to pass around your callback, then you must capture `a1` by moving:

```
b1->SetCB([ptr=std::move(a1)](std::vector<int> a, int b){ptr->Show(a,b);};
```

Then your callback function will gain ownership of the object that `a1` pointed to.